# Parse and storing objects locally on iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, core-data, parse-platform

I'm creating an iOS application that has a Twitter-like feed of data. I'm currently planning on storing the data on Parse. However, what is the most efficient way to store retrieved objects locally for use when there does not exist a network connection? It sounds like using Core Data is overkill since I'm storing the data on Parse anyway. Can the Parse caching system do this for me or is there something else more appropriate? On a similar note, is there a simple way to check if this locally saved data is up-to-date?

Comment: Why don't you ask your question on the "Parse Help & Community" board?

Comment: I have posted several questions here and on the Parse community board. I get much better help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse has the capability to cache objects locally. If your app can tolerate the characteristics of caching, then just use that.

My own app will not, so I am using CoreData as my local store. My app has to be able to operate fully when disconnected from Parse, so I have to have something more than cached data. I looked at FTASync and found the concept very useful. When I got into the code though I realized I needed something much more robust, so I have ended up doing a completely new utility to sync Parse with CoreData. This is a huge job, so don't take it on unless your need is commensurate.

-Bob

Comment: Hi Bob. Thank you for the reply. When would cached data not be sufficient? Most of my application will be displaying information in a UITableView, so I imagine a cached implementation will be sufficient for this?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I can give you a specific case where caching fails. My App is medically related. I want very specific control of what data I have on the iPad and I want to know that it is not going to be discarded. My real problem is that I do not control the caching algorithm and so I don't feel I can trust it. When I started out I was writing specific code to communicate with my back end server. The complications of that were eating me alive. Using a synchronization metaphor instead is WAY easier on the brain. My App is mostly ignorant of backend issues. Login and signup are exceptions.

Comment: I see. Well I guess I will just have to try Parse's caching system to see how effective it is. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you have a look at SQLite, especially with the `FMDB` Objective-C wrapper classes.